# Python - SOAP Server did not recognize value of HTTP Header

Tags: python, soap

First time using SOAP, and I've found multiple instances of similar error messages, but nothing that appears to apply to me.

Code is written in Python (3.5).

Here is the exact example from the site I'm trying to make the request to:

```
POST /WS/OpenAPI.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: bms.kaseya.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://bms.kaseya.com/Authenticate"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Authenticate xmlns="https://bms.kaseya.com/">
      <companyName>string</companyName>
      <userName>string</userName>
      <password>string</password>
    </Authenticate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am using Requests in Python and all seems to be going good with:

```
import requests

companyName = 'My Company'
userName = 'My Username'
password = 'My Password'

url = 'https://bms.kaseya.com/WS/OpenAPI.asmx'

body = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Authenticate xmlns="https://bms.kaseya.com/">
      <companyName>{}</companyName>
      <userName>{}</userName>
      <password>{}</password>
    </Authenticate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''.format(companyName,userName,password)

headers = {'Host':'bms.kaseya.com',
           'Content-Type':'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
           'Content-Length':str(len(body)),
           'SOAPAction':'"https://bms.kaseya.com/Authenticate"'}

r = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Except for the part where I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: https://bms.kaseya.com/Authenticate.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

From what I've found it seems that the url of the SOAPAction is wrong??? I'm literally taking their example and just inserting my live information, I've no clue where I've gone wrong, if it even is me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard it's been fixed. My code is fine, as expected this was due to bad documentation on their part. A slight fix of some URLs and everything works as expected!

Turns out we go with SOAP 1.2 and the proper example should have been:

```
POST /WS/OpenAPI.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: bms.kaseya.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Authenticate xmlns="https://vorexlogin.com/">
      <companyName>string</companyName>
      <userName>string</userName>
      <password>string</password>
    </Authenticate>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```